# How should we deal with moderators who are making bad calls?

Tags: self-moderation, mistakes

If you have a moderator who keeps making bad calls, such as by banning people who shouldn't be banned, what is the best way to deal with them?

Should you remove them from their positions, talk to them about it, and make sure they make better calls?  If now, how should you deal with it?

Comment: Where do the moderators draw their authority from? That's crucial to any question about moderating moderators.

Comment: @Gilles What do you mean "Draw their authority from"?

Comment: Who wrote the rules of moderation? Who decides who is appointed to be a moderator, or delegated that power?

Comment: @Gilles The admin

Comment: Since you're asking if you should remove them from their positions, does that mean you have the power to remove them?

Comment: Yes, this is being asked from an administrators perspective.

Answer (score 4):

Your fellow moderators should be open to criticism and be willing to account for mistakes.  The first thing should involve talking to them about it if *you* are concerned about something.  If there are others, you can first ask them if they want to say something as well.  Don't start off by "ganging-up" on anyone.

You can start off by mentioning the specific issues, why you think they were wrong, and what you think can be done better.  In milder cases, the other moderator will take them to heart and improve on them.

However, it may only be necessary to step it up first if these actions are causing real harm to the site.  In such a case, merely talking to them may not be enough (though it could still be a start), and a higher-up may need to warn them before possibly revoking their powers.

Comment: I would agree with you there. They need to be open to others pointing out their mistakes, but if they still deny they did the wrong thing, what should you do then?

Comment: @Dozer789: As I've said, you may need to talk to a higher-up, especially if pointing them to *official documentation* is not sufficient.  It may be a little different if there are some grey areas, and if so, then perhaps all the moderators should discuss how best to handle it.  Not only can it (hopefully) sway the other moderator, but also clear some other misconceptions felt by others.