# How should I resolve a disagreement with another moderator?

Tags: conflict-resolution, moderators

I am one of several moderators on my site.  Sometimes another moderator handles an issue in a way I disagree with strongly -- deleted something, closed a question I thought should stay open, etc.  For the sake of this question, assume that these actions are publicly visible (I'm not talking about, say, private actions with users).

Since the action was public, maybe I should raise my objection publicly, the same way any user would or could.  On the other hand, perhaps maintaining a unified appearance among all the mods is important.  On the third hand, maybe mods shouldn't be deciding privately things that could be discussed in public with broader input.  And I've exceeded my hand limit, but there are probably yet other factors.

So, how should I decide where and how to question or challenge another moderator's action?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How should we deal with moderators who are making bad calls?](http://moderators.stackexchange.com/questions/13/how-should-we-deal-with-moderators-who-are-making-bad-calls)

Comment: @Jamal: Not really, it's implied here that the two moderators have the same status, while in the other question, it's from a point of admin to moderator.

Comment: Hmm, didn't see that one.  But that one seems to be more about "how do we, collectively, deal with this problem mod", while I'm asking "how do two mods, both behaving well but disagreeing, resolve those differences".  That feels different to me.

Comment: Ah, I see.  I'll keep it here to see how this review task is handled.

Comment: @Jamal I think the questions are related, but not duplicates.

Answer (score 4):

From your description, it looks like you don't have enough rules or standards. You need to make a solid ground where you and other mods agree on what is the lowest level in each case.

Where I mod, and make judgements in comments, I flag for other mods on the site to initiate a discussion whether to move further or stop at a comment. Never ever close or delete some posts on arbitrarily reasons.

Communicate, compromise and get your read on "theory of moderation" where less is more.

Answer (score 0):

I like to follow the "third is scared" rule. Ask a random third moderator, and whatever he says is sacred.

Of course, that doesn't come before communication and conflict resolution. Get together in some private chat room, hangouts, wrestling arena or whatever medium you pick, and <s>punch</s> talk it out.

Comment: So just to connect the dots, you suggest a private discussion rather than a public one?  (Well, I guess the wrestling match could go either way. :-) )

Comment: @MonicaCellio: Yes. Moderation details should remain as private as possible for as long as possible. A moderator is *still* a highly valued member of the community, and he at least deserves the benefit of not being publicly told off immediately.